# Interface as parameter or generic type constraint? What is standard practice?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

In class we have a simple task to learn about abstract classes, interfaces and inheritance.
For the first time I've seen that you can pass an interface as type rather than a class implementing the interface.

According to the title, which is more standard practice?
In this example both works and I'm pretty sure both will always work just that the generic has more flexibility?

```
public interface IPerson {}
public abstract class Person : IPerson
{
    protected Person() {}
}
public class Employee : Person
{   
    public Employee() : base() {}
}

public class PersonManager<T> where T : IPerson
{
    private List<T> people = new List<T>();
}
//OR
public class PersonManager
{
    private List<IPerson> people = new List<IPerson>();
}
```

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure both will always work"* - not necessarily. The first version has to specify a single type for the list, the second one allows any type that implements `IPerson` to be added to the `people` list. So depending on what you are doing one or the other version may be better

Comment: I'd also recommend adding the correct language tag - since those details may vary by programming language (I'm reasonably certain you're asking about C# based on the code snippet)

Comment: In my opinion I'd say the second case is more correct. Imagine you had a `PersonManager<Employee>`, that would be an `EmployeeManager` right? The consumer of this class shouldn't need to know what implementation of `IPerson` is inside it, and if they _do_ need it, it's likely that you should extract a different interface for the common functionality

Comment: Need more context. How will `people` be used?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should use the non generic version. Trying to make everything generic will make your code and classes unnecessarily complicated.

There are a few reasons to use the generic version:

1. You want to ensure all Persons are of the same type. See also the somewhat related ["Curiously recurring template pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)
2. Your `people` field is public. This would in effect make your class a specialized  generic collection, so all the reasons to use generic collections may apply.
3. Performance. A generic class will make the jitter generate code for each different type. This can allow some optimizations not otherwise possible. But as always with optimization, profile and measure before doing anything. Do not blindly follow rules without understanding the context where they apply.

There are probably more cases where generics are useful, this is just the main ones that come to mind.

But you should try to keep the code as simple and readable as possible. So use regular plain polymorphism unless you have some reason to do otherwise.